# Two arrays - pair elements with different index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help. There is an object. I want to create a new array which will contain paired elements from groupOne and one element from groupTwo. Trick is that a1 cannot be paired with a2, and b1 cannot be paired with b2... You get the point.

```
let groups = {
    groupOne: [ a1, b1, c1, d1 ],
    groupTwo: [ a2, b2, c2, d2 ],
}
```

Final goal is to get array like this

```
pairs = [
    [a1, c2],
    [c1, d2],
    [b1, a2],
    [d1, b2]
]
```

The code below is my attempt. Idea is when there are two different indexes, move chosen element from both arrays (groupOne and groupTwo) to the end of array and remove them. First problem is when index === groupTwoRandomIndex. Second problem is after few iterations c1 and c2 are picked.

```
let pairs = groups.groupOne.map((team, index, arr) => {
        let groupTwoRandomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * groups.groupTwo.length)

        if (index !== groupTwoRandomIndex ){
            let temp
            groups.groupOne.push(groups.groupOne.splice(index, 1)[0])
            groups.groupTwo.push(groups.groupTwo.splice(groupTwoRandomIndex, 1)[0])
            temp = [arr[groups.groupOne.length], groups.groupTwo[groups.groupTwo.length]]
            groups.groupOne.pop()
            groups.groupTwo.pop()
        }
    })
```

Comment: Does it have to be randomised? You could just try shifting the second array along by 1.

Comment: May we please understand **A)** What is the context of `teams.unseeded`? **B)** Are `a1, a2, b1, b2 ....` string values (ie: `'a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', ...`) and does one need to compare the first character of the `string` to make sure they are different? **C)** It seems you need a sort of **conditional randomization** - where a random element from groupTwo is accepted/rejected based on a condition. Is that a fair understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I have written a solution which does what your statement says. I have assumed that we cannot pick an element twice.

> Note that there can be multiple solutions to this problem.

```js
let groups = {
  groupOne: ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1"],
  groupTwo: ["a2", "b2", "c2", "d2"]
};

let pairs = [];

let alreadySelected = {};
const maximum = groups.groupTwo.length - 1;
const minimum = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < groups.groupOne.length; i++) {
  let randomnumber =
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;

  while (randomnumber === i || alreadySelected[groups.groupTwo[randomnumber]]) {
    randomnumber =
      Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
  }

  pairs.push([groups.groupOne[i], groups.groupTwo[randomnumber]]);
}

console.log("Pairs ", pairs);
```

Comment: I have a hunch that this question is some sort of "team matching" problem. The two arrays are winners from a previous round (or a round-robin-level) of some tournament. And, the OP is trying to create a match-schedule such that each team in group-1 plays another in group-2 which are not at the same position/index. If so, it may be unsuitable to match the same team from either groups more than once.

Comment: jsNoob is right. I'm trying to create an algorithm which will pair chess players after group phase is finished. I putted it that way because it's simple to understand

Answer (score -1):

Relatively easy solution with map, as you can just `zip` the array.

```js
let groups = {
    groupOne: [ "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1" ],
    groupTwo: [ "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2" ],
}

console.log(groups.groupOne.map((elem, index) => [elem, groups.groupTwo[index]]))
```

Comment: Consider reading the whole question (or at least the first paragraph): `…a1 cannot be paired with a2, and b1 cannot be paired with b2... `